# Angular: caching of images when using img ng-src in firefox seems broken

Tags: javascript, angularjs, browser-cache, http-caching

I'm working on a real-time photosharing website. It allows users across the world to look at photos together and post comments on them, with a real-time view of who is looking at what.

I used to use jQuery DOM manipulation (insertion of `<img>` tags) to show different images based on what the user clicked, and recently replaced this presentation logic with an Angular controller with an ng-src directive.

The logic works overall, but I noticed that on Firefox, Angular makes a GET request every single time I change the ng-src value, when I expect that image to be cached on the browser.

If you go here: http://dev14-www.photozzap.com/conference/j4bxpt3n , then open up Firebug / Net view, and switch back and forth between two photos, you will see that it makes GET requests for the image even though those images should be in the cache.

The impact is that the user will see some lag between the time they click on a photo and the time it actually displays.

On Chrome, the Developer / Net view clearly shows that the image is pulled from the cache when switching back and forth between images.

Can my code be fixed to allow images to be cached on Firefox or is there an Angular issue there ? Chrome seems to be doing the right thing.

Answer (score 1):

I'm on Firefox 24, and I can confirm, that requests are actually made every time I switch between photos, but... As you can see by investigating details of such request, server responds with 304 Not Modified, so image data itself isn't transfered over and over again so performance won't suffer much.

Even though firefox has stored image in cache, it's making a request to check if the image has been changed, upon seeing 304 response it just displays the local version of the file.

Comment: I've taken another look at this. It seems like Firefox 24, freshly launched, does properly use images from cache. If my firefox has been up for a few hours, it all of a sudden starts making GET requests everytime I switch between photos.

Comment: I've experimented with this some more, and found that if I use Firebug, Firefox's cache will sometimes behave in an unexpected way (do GET requests for objects which I expect to be cached). I realize the Net panel in Firebug has a "disable browser cache" option, but the unexpected behavior sometimes comes even not enabling this option. If I use a freshly launched Firefox session where Firebug has never been activated, I see proper caching behavior.

Comment: I have noticed this behavior as well, but I only get 304 if the initial request returned 304, and it doesn't take into account any max-age or Expires headers. If the intial request was a 200, it will continue to get a 200 response since it doesn't send and If-Modified-Since in subsequent requests. This seems like a bug, Chrome doesn't behave this way. If this is related to firebug it might not be a real issue, will need to check proxy logs to be sure.

Comment: Indeed seem to be related to Firebug. If firebug is disabled, I can't see any trace of these requests.

Comment: To be sure just disabled firebug or other extenstions of that kind, and just check access logs on your web server. Do you see requests to those images from your IP? If not, you're good.

Answer (score 1):

This is a firebug issue. If you inspect your traffic with a proxy, you will see that without firebug activated, it will not request the images from the server again, so any regular user will be fine.